# What's wrong here? Several errors on 2 lines. Unrecoverable syntax error. (0% scanned)

Tags: javascript

This piece of code is throwing 5 errors. I'm new to this and I just can't figure it out.

```
window._wpemojiSettings = {
    "baseUrl":"https:\/\/s.w.org\/images\/core\/emoji\/11\/72x72\/",
    "ext":".png",
    "svgUrl":"https:\/\/s.w.org\/images\/core\/emoji\/11\/svg\/",
    "svgExt":".svg",
    "source"{"concatemoji":"https:\/\/maidservicealexandria.com\/wp-includes\/js\/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=4.9.8"}
};
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. The errors are as follows:

`Expected an identifier and instead saw '}'`

`Expected '}' to match '{' from line 2 and instead saw 'https://s.w.org/images/core/emoji/11/svg/'.`

`Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.`

`Missing semicolon.`

`Unrecoverable syntax error. (0% scanned).`

Comment: You need to add ":" (colon) after the key "source"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.